# Angular Ionic: Property 'json' doesn't exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm creating an Ionic 2 project that shows github users and their details.
I've created Service file called github-users.ts and compiler showing me this error
in .json() method.

> Property 'json' doesn't exist on type 'Object'

Here my ***github-users.ts*** source file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

import { User } from "../../models/user";

@Injectable()
export class GithubUsersProvider {
  githubApiUrl = 'api.github.com';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { 
    console.log("Hello Github Users service");
   }

  load(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.githubApiUrl}/users`)
      .map(res => <User[]>res.json());
  }
}
```

And I'm getting this error from console

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GithubUsersProvider -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[GithubUsersProvider -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GithubUsersProvider -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[GithubUsersProvider -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
    at _createClass (core.js:10933)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10907)
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
    at _createClass (core.js:10933)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10907)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
    at nav-controller-base.js:263
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```

Comment: import HttpClientModule in your app.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import HttpClientModule to your app.module.ts under imports

```
imports:[
  HttpClientModule
]
```

Comment: Now I'm getting new error.  ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function

Comment: when you are using httpclient you do not need to use res.json. just return res

Answer (score 0):

Your error is  =  [No provider for HttpClient!]
 this type of error occurs when you does not define http module in **app.modules.ts** file.
  so firstly check it.

exp: 
  import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

imports: [ HttpModule]